# Keep fixed text on the right side of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in which the user can write a number.
I also need to write a text on the right side of the `EditText`, that is the unit of measure of the number written.

The user cannot edit the unit, but only the number.
So, is there a way to allow the user to write (on the left side as always) and also keep a text on the right side of the `EditText`?

Comment: you can add TextView on the right side of edittext by putting it into relativelayout.it will remains as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TextView` on the right of your `EditText`.

Then, you add a `TextWatcher` on your `EditText`.